# Manual Install of Xcode command line tools still isn't working

Tags: ruby, xcode, command-line, jekyll

I've manually installed the Xcode command line tools from the Apple website, and I went through the install process but it doesn't seem to be working. I ran this from the terminal to see if it installed:

```
Marissa-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro-2:~ marissamontgomery$ pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
package-id: com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables
version: 5.1.0.0.1.1396320587
volume: /
location: /
install-time: 1398301024
groups: com.apple.FindSystemFiles.pkg-group com.apple.DevToolsBoth.pkg-group com.apple.DevToolsNonRelocatableShared.pkg-group
```

So it looks like the command line tools have installed, but when I run this:

```
Marissa-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro-2:~ marissamontgomery$ xcode-select --install
```

A popup says: The `xcode-select` command requires the command line developer tools. Would you like to install the tools now?

I clicked install and then it said: Can't install the software because it is not currently available from the Software Update server.

I've read on other answers that the solution is to do a manual install, but I just did that so I don't understand why it's not working. Also, in Xcode downloads, it's not showing the Command Line Tools.

I've tried installing it manually many times so I don't know why it's not working.

Installing Jekyll still won't work:

```
Marissa-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro-2:~ marissamontgomery$ sudo gem install jekyll
Password:
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing jekyll:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
```

EDIT: `echo $PATH` returns this:

```
Marissa-Montgomerys-MacBook-Pro-2:~ marissamontgomery$ echo $PATH
/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/Users/marissamontgomery/.rvm/bin
```

Comment: in Terminal, type in "`echo $PATH`" and edit your question to show what appears.  I'm wondering if you are missing "`/usr/bin`"?

Comment: This looks to be a near exact copy of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23260748/230449). See my answer on that one.